# How to send post request with content-type x-www-form-urlencoded android retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, x-www-form-urlencoded

I am facing problem sending post request with content-type as x-www-form-urlencoded in android retrofit. Not sure about the error I am making while sending post request. When same request is send via postman, I can receive expected correct response. Moreover, I tried sending same response via html form and received successful response

```
public class RequestManager {

    private static Retrofit retrofit;

    private static final String BASE_URL = "https://ipguat.apps.net.pk/Ecommerce/api/Transaction/";
    private OkHttpClient okhttpClient;

    static Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create();

    public static Retrofit getRetrofitInstance() {
        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new retrofit2.Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }

}
```

//MainActivity from where I am sending post request

```
 private void sendPayment(String token) {
        Date c = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String formattedDate = df.format(c);
        Call<ResponseBody> call = service.sendPayment("102", "Arfeen Test", token, "00", "5", "03451234567", "arfeen@arfeen.me", "POSTMAN-TEST-ARF", "01", "Test Purchase", "www.facebook.com", "www.google.com", "TEST-01", formattedDate, "www.youtube.com");
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
                         @Override
                         public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                             if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                                 try {
                                     renderPage(response.body().string());
                                 } catch (IOException e) {
                                     e.printStackTrace();
                                 }
                             }
                         }

                         @Override
                         public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                             Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Something went wrong...Please try later!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                         }
                     }
        );


    }
```

// Interface where endpoint for API is mentioned

```
public interface TokenService {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("PostTransaction/")
    Call<ResponseBody> sendPayment(@Field("MERCHANT_ID") String id,
                                   @Field("MERCHANT_NAME") String merchantName,
                                   @Field("TOKEN") String token,
                                   @Field("PROCCODE") String proccode,
                                   @Field("TXNAMT") String transaction,
                                   @Field("CUSTOMER_MOBILE_NO") String mobile,
                                   @Field("CUSTOMER_EMAIL_ADDRESS") String email,
                                   @Field("SIGNATURE") String signature,
                                   @Field("VERSION") String version,
                                   @Field("TXNDESC") String productDescription,
                                   @Field("SUCCESS_URL") String successUrl,
                                   @Field("FAILURE_URL") String failureUrl,
                                   @Field("BASKET_ID") String basketID,
                                   @Field("ORDER_DATE") String orderDate,
                                   @Field("CHECKOUT_URL") String checoutUrl);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use @Headers annotation.

```
public interface TokenService {

    @FormUrlEncoded
    @Headers("Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    @POST("PostTransaction/")
    Call<ResponseBody> sendPayment(@Field("MERCHANT_ID") String id,
                                   @Field("MERCHANT_NAME") String merchantName,
                                   @Field("TOKEN") String token,
                                   @Field("PROCCODE") String proccode,
                                   @Field("TXNAMT") String transaction,
                                   @Field("CUSTOMER_MOBILE_NO") String mobile,
                                   @Field("CUSTOMER_EMAIL_ADDRESS") String email,
                                   @Field("SIGNATURE") String signature,
                                   @Field("VERSION") String version,
                                   @Field("TXNDESC") String productDescription,
                                   @Field("SUCCESS_URL") String successUrl,
                                   @Field("FAILURE_URL") String failureUrl,
                                   @Field("BASKET_ID") String basketID,
                                   @Field("ORDER_DATE") String orderDate,
                                   @Field("CHECKOUT_URL") String checoutUrl);

}
```

Try set up OkhttpClient,

***OkhttpManager.java***

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;

import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;

import okhttp3.Cookie;
import okhttp3.CookieJar;
import okhttp3.HttpUrl;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;
import okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor;

public class OkHttpManager {
    private final String TAG = "OkHttpManager";
    private final int TIME_OUT_SECONDS = 60;
    private static OkHttpManager instance = null;
    private WebViewCookieHandler mWebViewCookieHandler = null;

    public static OkHttpManager getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new OkHttpManager();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private OkHttpManager() {
        if (mWebViewCookieHandler == null)
            mWebViewCookieHandler = new WebViewCookieHandler();
    }

    private static ArrayList<String> sCurCookies = new ArrayList<>();

    OkHttpClient getOkHttpClientDefault(Context context) {
        // init okhttp 3 logger
        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        try {
            final TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{
                    new X509TrustManager() {
                        @Override
                        public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                            return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[]{};
                        }
                    }
            };

            return new OkHttpClient()
                    .newBuilder()
                    .cookieJar(mWebViewCookieHandler)
                    .hostnameVerifier((s, sslSession) -> true)
                    .connectTimeout(TIME_OUT_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .readTimeout(TIME_OUT_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .writeTimeout(TIME_OUT_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .addInterceptor(interceptor)
                    .addInterceptor(chain -> {
                        Request.Builder builder = chain.request().newBuilder();
                        return chain.proceed(builder.build());
                    })
                    .addInterceptor(chain -> {
                        Response response = chain.proceed(chain.request());

                        if (!response.headers("Set-Cookie").isEmpty()) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "getCookie header added");
                            sCurCookies.addAll(response.headers("Set-Cookie"));
                        }
                        response.body();
                        return response;
                    })
                    .build();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }

    private class WebViewCookieHandler implements CookieJar {
        private CookieManager webviewCookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();

        @Override
        public void saveFromResponse(HttpUrl url, List<Cookie> cookies) {
            String urlString = url.toString();

            for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
                webviewCookieManager.setCookie(urlString, cookie.toString());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public List<Cookie> loadForRequest(HttpUrl url) {
            String urlString = url.toString();
            String cookiesString = webviewCookieManager.getCookie(urlString);
            if (cookiesString != null && !cookiesString.isEmpty()) {
                //We can split on the ';' char as the cookie manager only returns cookies
                //that match the url and haven't expired, so the cookie attributes aren't included
                String[] cookieHeaders = cookiesString.split(";");
                List<Cookie> cookies = new ArrayList<>(cookieHeaders.length);

                for (String header : cookieHeaders) {
                    cookies.add(Cookie.parse(url, header));
                }
                return cookies;
            }
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }
    }
}
```

***RequestManager.java***

```
public class RequestManager {

    private static Retrofit retrofit;

    private static final String BASE_URL = "https://ipguat.apps.net.pk/Ecommerce/api/Transaction/";
    private OkHttpClient okhttpClient;

    static Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create();

    public static Retrofit getRetrofitInstance(Activity activity) {
        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new retrofit2.Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .client(OkHttpManager.getInstance().getOkHttpClientDefault(activity))
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }

}
```

Comment: Sorry still same error for invalid request even after trying @Headers annotation

Comment: @TahaAsif OkhttpClient is not in use, is it still undeveloped?

Comment: @TahaAsif Try reapplying with what I just modified

Comment: You are Awesome... Thanks :)

Comment: Client settings are more important than you think. There are more options for Okhttp3, so check it out and apply it :)